# What simple slideshow software would show JPEG images in a folder with alpha blending transition?

Tags: software, jpeg, windows-7, slideshow

Who can recommend me a **simple** slideshow software that simply shows JPG images in a folder **and allows alpha-blending** between the slides? I really don't need more than that. The standard Windows 7 photoviewer slideshow feature would be enough if it had the simple alpha blending effect (or any comparable, *simple* transition effect).

No software that needs to create WMV/AVI/MPG/... movies, instead some ad-hoc software, please.

I tried IrfanView, but for some reason it doesn't get the alpha blending right (may be a bug). Lightroom's Slideshow feature uses too much ressources when sliding through RAW slides.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

**Picasa Photo Viewer**, which gets installed together with **[Picasa](http://picasa.google.com/)**, has a simple slideshow feature with an alpha-transparency/blending transition effect.

<sub>*Note: Picasa Photo Viewer is not currently available for Mac.*</sub>

Comment: While I have not tried it for a while, the version I tried (2 yrs or so ago) was terrible an useless because it cropped the frames when they did not have the same aspect ratio as the screen. Since it is free, at least it does not hurt to try.

Answer (score 0):

Picasa is the best for simple stuff. And its free. And provides lots of options.
http://picasa.google.com/

Answer (score 0):

How hard and fast is your alpha blending requirement?  The simplest viewer I know is VueSlide.  I use it often for simple CDs I give to people.  It is easy to get it to auto start and show all the pictures on a CD.  It take very little room and just shows pictures.  However it does not do *any* transitions just flips from pic to pic.

If it seems interesting you can get it here: the [Vue Slide](http://www.hamrick.com/upg.html) link is lower on the page under "Other Useful Files".

Comment: a transition of about 1 second would be optimal. just a linear A->B transition would be enough.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to check out our PicaJet: http://picajet.com.

If has the alpha blenging effect, but you should really enjoy from the "Smelt" effect that is a complex combination of alpha blending depended from picture content. And it's unique for each new picture in your collection. It has a free version that support this effect.